# C++ template programming design question - return different type according to input file

Tags: c++, templates, run-time-polymorphism

A multimedia file may have data of different date types such as uint8_t, int16_t, float, etc. Below three examples show file content with the first byte indicate data type:

```
1st File: 0,<uint8 data><uint8 data><uint8 data>...
2nd File: 1,<int16 data><int16 data><int16 data>...
3rd File: 2,<float data><float data><float data>...
```

A FileReader class read a file and return different types of DataStream. I use DataStreamBase so that client hold a pointer.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
class FileReader {
    DataStreamBase* readFile(string filename) {
        switch (first_byte) {   // the first byte in a file.
        case 0:
            return new DataStream<uint8_t>();
        case 1:
            return new DataStream<int16_t>();
        case 2:
            return new DataStream<float>();
        case 3:
        // ... there are many more "case <n>:"
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class DataStreamBase {
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
class DataStream : public DataStreamBase {

private:
  T* data_;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// client 
int main() {
    FileReader reader;
    DataStreamBase* stream = reader.readFile("some file name");

    // Question: how to get a pointer to the data which may be uint8_t, int16_t, or float. Below approach is ugly.
    //uint8_t* data = stream->getDataUint8();
    //int16_t* data = stream->getDataInt16();
    //float* data = stream->getDataFloat();
    //...
}
```

The client don't know whether input file contains uint8_t, int16_t, or float data until run-time.

Question:
How client get a pointer to uint8_t, int16_t, float, ... which can be passed to a third-party library? Is this design a right approach to this kind of problem? Thanks.

Comment: _"Is this design a right approach to this kind of problem?"_ It's probably opinion based. But I would say this is a possible approach. But what is your question? Do you expect a yes/no answer?

Comment: The question is "How client get a pointer so that it can pass it to a third-party program for process?".

Comment: Are you aware that a pointer is just a memory address? You can pass that pointer but the data won't be there. You can either pass all data or you have to use shared memory. By default programs don't share memory.

Comment: Pass the pointer to a library, not application.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I settled with a solution of double dispatch. This is not the solution to the original question, but it avoid the problem of writing duplicated code.

The reason to use double dispatch is that client need read two files and call third party program by passing two data streams. The third party program has interface as:

```
template<class T>
int calculate(const T* input_1, const T* input_2, vector<float>& result);
```

Without double dispatch, client need call third party program like this:

```
DataStreamBase * ds1;
DataStreamBase * ds2;
if (auto cast_ds1 = dynamic_cast<DataStream<uint8_t>*>(ds1)) {
  if (auto cast_ds2 = dynamic_cast<DataStream<uint8_t>*>(ds2)) {
    calculate(cast_ds1->getData(), cast_ds2->getData(), result);
  }
  else if (auto cast_ds2 = dynamic_cast<DataStream<int16_t>*>(ds2)) {
    calculate(cast_ds1->getData(), cast_ds2->getData(), result);
  }
  ...
}
else if (auto cast_ds1 = dynamic_cast<DataStream<int16_t>*>(ds1)) {
  if (auto cast_ds2 = dynamic_cast<DataStream<uint8_t>*>(ds2)) {
    calculate(cast_ds1->getData(), cast_ds2->getData(), result);
  }
  else if ...
}
...
```

Please note that template class DataStream define method "const T* getData()", whereas base class DataStreamBase cannot define getData() method because it don't know what return type is.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
class DataStream : public DataStreamBase {
public:
   const T* getData() const { return data_; }

private:
  T* data_;
};
```

Using TypeList and StaticDispatch from the book "Modern C++ Design", I am able to let compiler generate those duplicated code for me using template technique. This sketch the idea:

client (main.cpp):

```
   using MyTypeList = TYPELIST_6(DataStreamBase<uint8_t>, DataStream<int16_t>, DataStream<int32_t>, DataStream<int64_t>, DataStream<float>, AudioStream<double>);

  using DataStreamDispatcher = DoubleDispatcher<Calculator, int, std::vector<float>, DataStreamBase, DataStreamTypeList>;

  DataStreamDispatcher::DispatchT1(*ds1, *ds2, calculator, calculate));
```

calculator.cpp:

```
class Calculator {
public:

  // this api is 3rd party library.
  template<class T1, class T2>
  int calculate(const T1*, int, const T2*, int, std::vector<float>&);

  template<class T1, class T2>
  int applyDoubleDispatch(const T1& s1, const T2& s2, std::vector<float>& res)
  {
    return calculate(s1.getData(), s2.getData(), res);
  }
  ...
};
```

doubledispatch.cpp:

```
  template<class Executor, class ResType, class ParamType, class T1, class TypeList1, class T2 = T1, class TypeList2 = TypeList1>
  class DoubleDispatcher {
  public:
    static ResType DispatchT1(T1& obj1, T2& obj2, Executor exec, ParamType& param) {
      using HeadType = typename TypeList1::HeadType;
      using TailType = typename TypeList1::TailType;
      if (HeadType* t1 = dynamic_cast<HeadType*>(&obj1)) {
        return DoubleDispatcher<Executor, ResType, ParamType, HeadType, TypeList1, T2, TypeList2>::DispatchT2(*t1, obj2, exec, param);
      }
      else {
        return DoubleDispatcher<Executor, ResType, ParamType, T1, TailType, T2, TypeList2>::DispatchT1(obj1, obj2, exec, param);
      }
    }
  
    static ResType DispatchT2(T1& obj1, T2& obj2, Executor exec, ParamType& param) {
      using HeadType = typename TypeList2::HeadType;
      using TailType = typename TypeList2::TailType;
      if (HeadType* t2 = dynamic_cast<HeadType*>(&obj2)) {
        return exec.applyDoubleDispatch(obj1, *t2, param);
      }
      else{
        return DoubleDispatcher<Executor, ResType, ParamType, T1, TypeList1, T2, TailType>::DispatchT2(obj1, obj2, exec, param);
      }
    }
  };

  // see the book for code of specialization when T1 and T2 are not supported
```